# Add Reference/Issue number to webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Hi I am using Visual Studio 2013, c# asp.net. I have created a online docket for staff to fill out, I was wondering can you add a reference number/ issue number to the web form. Each staff member will fill out this form and they could be similar, so I want each form to have there own unique number however I am not to sure which way to go about it. The form is going to be the same for everyone so I want each one that is filled out to have a different number. Should I place a label and have an array list to generate random numbers or is there a more straight forward way?

Comment: Have you found a suitable solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a number in a database. On each form generated, take this number, increment it, and save the new number to the DB.

Comment: Based on your answer, imagine the following scenario: The `number` in the database is currently at `7`. Two users open the form at the same time, User1 reads `7` as being the latest from the DB and `increments it` as per your suggestion. User2 also reads `7` and increments this number. What happens when both users then try to save their records and both have `8` as their `new number`?

Comment: This still does not make your GUI a human friendly option... while there are lots of ways to extend my answer, to combat all possible scenarios of duplicates. Have you ever noticed a million other systems using incremental numbering, successfully?

Comment: You are completely missing the point. Of course it is possible, I am basing this answer on what I believe the OP has asked: `Should I place a label and have an array list to generate random numbers or is there a more straight forward way`.

Comment: Yeah fair that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to keeping a number in the database and having to detect collisions etc you could use the Guid: [Guid.NewGuid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx)

Sample usage:

```
Guid uniqueId = System.Guid.NewGuid();
string x = uniqueId.ToString();
```

Comment: I would think a GUID would be inappropriate / akward for a "reference" on a form...

Comment: I would think keeping track of a number coming from the database would be prone to error. You can generate GUIDs anywhere, instead of having to roundtrip to the database

Comment: Yes offcourse, but would you enjoy quoting a GUID when you refer to a form / document in the future? It seems like the OP want to hbind a unique reference to the form... to be used later, by humans.

Comment: The number is more readable but the overhead and amount of work that would be involved in implementing this feature versus using the Guid far outweighs the readability benefit in my opinion.

Comment: Not to play tit for tat, but do you currently have any reference to a document that you need to look up or produce at some point, in your professional or personal life, that has a GUID as its only unique reference to locate it?

Comment: It's irrelevant but yes I have come across GUID in real systems and being used as reference numbers.